# Latin1 to UTF8 conversion

Tags: mysql, database, encoding, utf-8, latin1

Before answring to my problem, Keep this in mind: I have searched for this problem many sites including mysql forum and stackoverflow. No answer solved my problem...

I have Mysql database encoded as latin1(Arabic characters), with huge data inserted as text and varchar.

I am trying to convert it to UTF8.
I have tried different conversion methods, I got data corruption when displayed in html as utf8 header.

Have any one tried this??

Please help

Comment: What different approaches have you already tried?

Comment: `latin1` doesn't have support for Arabic characters. How can your text be stored as `latin1`?